# how can I make two listviews fetching from two sqlite tables in one activity in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter

I have one activity in which I need to display two lists that fetch from two sqlite tables. for every list, I am writing a `customCursorAdapter` Can anyone guide me to a useful example, or just how to make such a scenario possible ? Thank you.

Comment: If you are able to populate one List , You should be able to populate the other list with the same/similar logic.

Comment: but there must be a listview with ID "list", and you can't have two item with the same ID in one layout. DO you have any example ? I know it's possible to do, and the idea is to define the adapters on your own, but I am still figuring out how to do it.

Comment: Dont use ListActivity .Create your own layout with two different listviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **layout** that will contain two lists-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvOne"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvTwo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And  your **class** which should extend the Activity class (Not ListActivity class) should be similar to this--

```
public class TwoListActivity extends Activity {

ListView lvOne ;
ListView lvTwo ;

MyAdapter adapter ; // Initialise your adapter

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two_list);

    lvOne = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvOne);
    lvTwo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTwo);

    lvOne.setAdapter(/*** Create and set your adapter****/);
    lvTwo.setAdapter(/*** Create and set your adapter****/);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have solved it using ListFragment, but your solution would work too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the data from db and store it in two separate arrayLists then pass each to corresponding listView adapter (You should have separate instance of the adapter for each listView)

Comment: I think the idea is on the right direction, just couldn't figure out how to make it work so far, do you have any example ? thank you :)